# SQL Nesting iteration to update one table from another ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I'm looking for a suggestion for the best way to accomplish the following task.  I need to run an SQL query that will pull up to 200 rows.  With each row, I need to take the data from that row and insert it into another table.  At first I thought I would nest database connections like the code example I've listed below.  However I was wondering if this was the incorrect way of doing it and what would be a better way.

Any ideas?

```
Dim dbconn As New SqlConnection
Dim dbconn2 As New SqlConnection
dbconn = New         SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("databaseName").ConnectionString
dbconn2 = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("databaseName").ConnectionString
dbconn.Open() 
Dim cmd As New SQLCommand
Dim cmd2 As New SQLCommand
Dim UserReader As SqlDataReader 

Dim cmdStringSource As String = "SELECT approx 25 fields WHERE fldRandomField = 26"
Dim cmdStringUpdate As String
cmd = New SQLCommnd(cmdStringSource, dbconn)
UserReader = cmdExecuteReader()
If UserReader.HasRows Then
While UserReader.Read()
    cmdStringUpdate = "UPDATE tblUpdate SET a whole bunch of stuff from the cmdStringSource current record"
    dbconn2.Open()
    cmd2=New SQLCommand(cmdStringUpdate, dbconn2)
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dbconn2.close()
End While
End If
UserReader.Close()
dbconn.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing this in the loop, with multiple connections and datareaders - do it entirely in the back end.

SQL Server supports Insert from select e.g.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (field1, field2, field3 ...)
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM FROM Table2 
WHERE <some condition>
```

Same goes for UPPDATE e.g.

```
UPDATE Table1
  SET Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field1,
      Table1.Field2 = Table2.Field2
      Table1.Field3 = Table2.Field3
  FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
  ON Table1.CommonField = Table2.CommonField
WHERE <some condition>
```

Just build this statement and call it once with a single connection and `ExecuteNonQuery` command.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Please mark as answered if solution worked for u